# preventing MobaXTerm sidebar from opening,

Tags: mobaxterm

I would like to not have to close the sidebar after opening a ssh session but i cannot find a way to stop it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to stop MobaXTerm from opening up the sidebar after connecting or even to remove the sidebar altogether. I have mobaxterm v10.5.

Comment: A solution appears in a separate thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43144418

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MobaXterm v10.5, you can do the following to avoid showing the sidebar:

Click on `View`→`Show/hide sidebar`.

This hides/shows the sidebar across all the tabs of MobaXterm.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I don't know how i missed that. :-)

Comment: no, this closes it once. reread the question

Answer (score 7):

I suggest disabling `Use SSH-browser (graphical remote file browser in the sidebar)` and `Automatically switch sidebar view to show the graphical SSH-browser` as suggested by the following Stack Overflow answer.

In newer versions of MobaXterm, these options were renamed to `Enable graphical SSH-browser` and `Automatically switch to SSH-browser tab after login`

> Under Settings, there are these 2 options that control this behavior
>   that I typically turn off.

[image]

Source:

- [Mobaxterm annoying sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097487/mobaxterm-annoying-sidebar)

Answer (score 1):

Just use slider hiding shortcut:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Personal Edition v23, unchecking 1 default check-box solves it
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Update for MobaXterm Personal Edition v22.1 Build 4888 (2022 Oct)

The settings menu has changed.

For each SSH User Session configuration one can turn off SFTP to prevent the sidebar from popping out in new sessions.

`SSH` => `Basic SSH settings` => `Advanced SSH settings` => `SSH-browser type` = `None`

After saving this will apply to new sessions, not restarted ones. Close affections sessions or relaunch MobaXTerm to apply the effect.

[SSH User Session configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l55Xq.png)